# omnet++ simulation crashes, when node shuts down

Tags: c++, omnet++

I'm working on powerusage optimized aodv and olsr (https://github.com/marcelebbrecht/powerrouting)

When my nodes run out of battery and shut down, my simulation crashes:

```
** Event #32188  t=8.579288289439  0% completed   

OLSR.router23.energyManagement (SimpleEpEnergyManagement, id=377)
[WARN]  Capacity reached node shutdown threshold
[INFO]  Doing stage 0/8 of operation inet::NodeShutdownOperation on OLSR.router23
[INFO]  OLSR.router23 shutting down
[INFO]  Doing stage 1/8 of operation inet::NodeShutdownOperation on OLSR.router23
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node  removes MPR selector tuple: nb_addr =
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node  removes MPR selector tuple: nb_addr =
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node  removes MPR selector tuple: nb_addr =
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes 2-hop neighbor tuple: nb_addr = ▒▒c nb2hop_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node  removes MPR selector tuple: nb_addr =
[INFO]  8.579288: Node 145.236.0.10 removes link tuple: nb_addr = 145.236.0.10
[INFO]  8.579288: Node 145.236.0.10 removes neighbor tuple: nb_addr = 145.236.0.10
[INFO]  8.579288: Node  removes MPR selector tuple: nb_addr =
[INFO]  8.579288: Node 145.236.0.10 removes link tuple: nb_addr = 145.236.0.10
[INFO]  8.579288: Node 145.236.0.10 removes neighbor tuple: nb_addr = 145.236.0.10
[INFO]  8.579288: Node  removes MPR selector tuple: nb_addr =
[INFO]  8.579288: Node 145.236.0.10 removes link tuple: nb_addr = 145.236.0.10
[INFO]  8.579288: Node 145.236.0.10 removes neighbor tuple: nb_addr = 145.236.0.10
[INFO]  8.579288: Node 145.236.0.10 removes link tuple: nb_addr = 145.236.0.10
[INFO]  8.579288: Node 145.236.0.10 removes neighbor tuple: nb_addr = 145.236.0.10
[INFO]  8.579288: Node 145.236.0.10 removes link tuple: nb_addr = 145.236.0.10
[INFO]  8.579288: Node 145.236.0.10 removes neighbor tuple: nb_addr = 145.236.0.10
[INFO]  8.579288: Node 145.236.0.10 removes link tuple: nb_addr = 145.236.0.10
[INFO]  8.579288: Node 145.236.0.10 removes neighbor tuple: nb_addr = 145.236.0.10
[INFO]  8.579288: Node 145.236.0.10 removes link tuple: nb_addr = 145.236.0.10
[INFO]  8.579288: Node 145.236.0.10 removes neighbor tuple: nb_addr = 145.236.0.10
[INFO]  8.579288: Node 145.236.0.10 removes link tuple: nb_addr = 145.236.0.10
[INFO]  8.579288: Node 145.236.0.10 removes neighbor tuple: nb_addr = 145.236.0.10
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 4
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 4
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 4
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 4
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 4
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 1
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 1
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes iface association tuple: main_addr = ▒▒c iface_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes iface association tuple: main_addr = ▒▒c iface_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes iface association tuple: main_addr = ▒▒c iface_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes iface association tuple: main_addr = ▒▒c iface_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 0
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 0
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes iface association tuple: main_addr = ▒▒c iface_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes iface association tuple: main_addr = ▒▒c iface_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes iface association tuple: main_addr = ▒▒c iface_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 1
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 1
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes iface association tuple: main_addr = ▒▒c iface_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes iface association tuple: main_addr = ▒▒c iface_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 4
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 4
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 4
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 4
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 4
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes iface association tuple: main_addr = ▒▒c iface_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 1
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 1
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes iface association tuple: main_addr = ▒▒c iface_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes iface association tuple: main_addr = ▒▒c iface_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes iface association tuple: main_addr = ▒▒c iface_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 6
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 6
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 6
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 6
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 6
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 6
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 6
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 3
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 3
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 3
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 3
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes iface association tuple: main_addr = ▒▒c iface_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes iface association tuple: main_addr = ▒▒c iface_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes iface association tuple: main_addr = ▒▒c iface_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes iface association tuple: main_addr = ▒▒c iface_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes iface association tuple: main_addr = ▒▒c iface_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 2
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 2
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 2
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 4
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 4
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 4
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 4
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes topology tuple: dest_addr = ▒▒c last_addr = ▒▒c seq = 4
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes iface association tuple: main_addr = ▒▒c iface_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes iface association tuple: main_addr = ▒▒c iface_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes iface association tuple: main_addr = ▒▒c iface_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes iface association tuple: main_addr = ▒▒c iface_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  8.579288: Node ▒▒c removes iface association tuple: main_addr = ▒▒c iface_addr = ▒▒c
[INFO]  Doing stage 2/8 of operation inet::NodeShutdownOperation on OLSR.router23
[INFO]  Doing stage 3/8 of operation inet::NodeShutdownOperation on OLSR.router23
[INFO]  Doing stage 4/8 of operation inet::NodeShutdownOperation on OLSR.router23
[INFO]  remove route dest:145.236.0.1  gw:145.236.0.5  mask:255.255.255.255  metric:2 if:wlan0(145.236.0.10)  REMOTE MANET
[INFO]  remove route dest:145.236.0.2  gw:145.236.0.5  mask:255.255.255.255  metric:2 if:wlan0(145.236.0.10)  REMOTE MANET
[INFO]  remove route dest:145.236.0.3  gw:145.236.0.7  mask:255.255.255.255  metric:2 if:wlan0(145.236.0.10)  REMOTE MANET
[INFO]  remove route dest:145.236.0.4  gw:145.236.0.15  mask:255.255.255.255  metric:4 if:wlan0(145.236.0.10)  REMOTE MANET
[INFO]  remove route dest:145.236.0.5  gw:145.236.0.5  mask:255.255.255.255  metric:1 if:wlan0(145.236.0.10)  REMOTE MANET
[INFO]  remove route dest:145.236.0.6  gw:145.236.0.6  mask:255.255.255.255  metric:1 if:wlan0(145.236.0.10)  REMOTE MANET
[INFO]  remove route dest:145.236.0.7  gw:145.236.0.7  mask:255.255.255.255  metric:1 if:wlan0(145.236.0.10)  REMOTE MANET
[INFO]  remove route dest:145.236.0.8  gw:145.236.0.7  mask:255.255.255.255  metric:2 if:wlan0(145.236.0.10)  REMOTE MANET
[INFO]  remove route dest:145.236.0.9  gw:145.236.0.15  mask:255.255.255.255  metric:3 if:wlan0(145.236.0.10)  REMOTE MANET
[INFO]  remove route dest:145.236.0.11  gw:145.236.0.11  mask:255.255.255.255  metric:1 if:wlan0(145.236.0.10)  REMOTE MANET
[INFO]  remove route dest:145.236.0.12  gw:145.236.0.15  mask:255.255.255.255  metric:2 if:wlan0(145.236.0.10)  REMOTE MANET
[INFO]  remove route dest:145.236.0.13  gw:145.236.0.13  mask:255.255.255.255  metric:1 if:wlan0(145.236.0.10)  REMOTE MANET
[INFO]  remove route dest:145.236.0.14  gw:145.236.0.14  mask:255.255.255.255  metric:1 if:wlan0(145.236.0.10)  REMOTE MANET
[INFO]  remove route dest:145.236.0.15  gw:145.236.0.15  mask:255.255.255.255  metric:1 if:wlan0(145.236.0.10)  REMOTE MANET
[INFO]  remove route dest:145.236.0.16  gw:145.236.0.15  mask:255.255.255.255  metric:2 if:wlan0(145.236.0.10)  REMOTE MANET
[INFO]  remove route dest:145.236.0.17  gw:145.236.0.15  mask:255.255.255.255  metric:3 if:wlan0(145.236.0.10)  REMOTE MANET
[INFO]  remove route dest:145.236.0.18  gw:145.236.0.13  mask:255.255.255.255  metric:2 if:wlan0(145.236.0.10)  REMOTE MANET
[INFO]  remove route dest:145.236.0.19  gw:145.236.0.13  mask:255.255.255.255  metric:2 if:wlan0(145.236.0.10)  REMOTE MANET
[INFO]  remove route dest:145.236.0.20  gw:145.236.0.15  mask:255.255.255.255  metric:2 if:wlan0(145.236.0.10)  REMOTE MANET
[INFO]  remove route dest:145.236.0.21  gw:145.236.0.15  mask:255.255.255.255  metric:3 if:wlan0(145.236.0.10)  REMOTE MANET
[INFO]  remove route dest:145.236.0.22  gw:145.236.0.22  mask:255.255.255.255  metric:1 if:wlan0(145.236.0.10)  REMOTE MANET
[INFO]  remove route dest:145.236.0.23  gw:145.236.0.15  mask:255.255.255.255  metric:3 if:wlan0(145.236.0.10)  REMOTE MANET
[INFO]  remove route dest:145.236.0.24  gw:145.236.0.7  mask:255.255.255.255  metric:2 if:wlan0(145.236.0.10)  REMOTE MANET
[INFO]  remove route dest:145.236.0.25  gw:145.236.0.15  mask:255.255.255.255  metric:2 if:wlan0(145.236.0.10)  REMOTE MANET
[INFO]  remove route dest:127.0.0.0  gw:*  mask:255.0.0.0  metric:1 if:lo0(127.0.0.1)  DIRECT IFACENETMASK
[INFO]  Doing stage 5/8 of operation inet::NodeShutdownOperation on OLSR.router23
[INFO]  Doing stage 6/8 of operation inet::NodeShutdownOperation on OLSR.router23
[INFO]  Transmission aborted: (inet::physicallayer::RadioFrame)UDPData-73 WHOLE as IdealTransmission, communicationRange = 250 m, interferenceRange = 350 m, detectionRange = 350 m, id = 459, transmitterId = 9, startTime = 8.578822834886, endTime = 8.579576289431, startPosition = (250, 400, 0), preambleDuration = 0, headerPosition = 0, dataPosition = 0.000753454545, endPosition = (250, 400, 0), startOrientation = (0, 0, 0), endOrientation = (0, 0, 0)
[WARN]  Aborting ongoing transmissions is not supported
[INFO]  Changing radio transmission state from TRANSMITTING to IDLE.
[INFO]  scheduling ACK timeout
[INFO]  Radio mode changed from TRANSMITTER to RECEIVER
[INFO]  Changing radio reception state from UNDEFINED to IDLE.
[INFO]  Changing radio transmission state from IDLE to UNDEFINED.
[INFO]  Changing radio transmitted signal part from WHOLE to NONE.
[INFO]  Radio mode changed from RECEIVER to OFF
[INFO]  Changing radio reception state from IDLE to UNDEFINED.
[INFO]  Doing stage 7/8 of operation inet::NodeShutdownOperation on OLSR.router23
[INFO]  OLSR.router23 shut down
** Event #32189  t=8.579324107621  0% completed   OLSR.router23.wlan[0].mac (CsmaCaMac, id=401)

<!> Error: Self message 'AckTimeout' received when CsmaCaMac is down -- in module (inet::CsmaCaMac) OLSR.router23.wlan[0].mac (id=401), at t=8.579324107621s, event #32189
[INFO]  Clear all sockets
[INFO]  Clear all sockets
```

Any hints? Code is online in branch version04

Comment: now in master branch

Comment: Without looking into your code, I'd guess from the error message that you have some timers scheduled and when you "shut down" your node, you forgot to check and cancel all running timers. So when the timer fires, it cannot be processed in handleMessage whatsoever because your node is down.

Comment: It happens also with vanilla inet - just enable csmacamac and let a node run out of power -> bam ...

Answer (score 2):

Solution: I patched a file in inet (src/inet/common/lifecycle/OperationalBase.cc), just exchange the method handleMessageWhenDown:

```
void OperationalBase::handleMessageWhenDown(cMessage *message)
{
    if (message->isSelfMessage())
        // following line is commented through errors when running out of power and mac use ack
        // now we send a message instead of throwing a runtime error, dunno if it's a dump hack ;)
        //throw cRuntimeError("Self message '%s' received when %s is down", message->getName(), getComponentType()->getName());
        EV_WARN << "Self message " << message->getName() << " received when " << getComponentType()->getName() << " is down" << endl;
    else if (simTime() == lastChange)
        EV_WARN << getComponentType()->getName() << " is down, dropping '" << message->getName() << "' message\n";
    else
        throw cRuntimeError("Message '%s' received when %s is down", message->getName(), getComponentType()->getName());
    delete message;
}
```

I'll do some deeper investigation later ... for the moment it works!